# Extension result for martingale measures

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a finite and bounded sequence of random variables $X_n, n=0,\dots,T$ ($T<\infty$) valued in some compact, convex set of an euclidean space.

If one knows that the $X_n$ are adapted to some filtration $\mathcal{F}_n,n=0,\dots,T$ then one knows the following Theorem is true.

**Theorem**

$X_n$ is a martingale w.r.t. filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$ if and only if for every stopping time $\tau$ adapted to $\mathcal{F}_n$ it holds

\begin{equation}\label{eq:help}
E[X_{\tau}] = X_0. 
\end{equation}

Now, suppose that you have less information about the $X_n$ than all of the joint distribution. I.e. suppose you know only enough information about the joint distribution of the $X_n$-s to check relation $E[X_{\tau}] = X_0$ not for all possible stopping times $\tau$ adapted to $\mathcal{F}_n$ but only for a subclass $\mathcal{T}$ of stopping times. Formally, the only information you have about the joint distribution of sequence $X_n$ is the following.

**Limited Observability Assumption.** You know for each $\tau\in\mathcal{T}$ and $n$ the conditional distributions 
$
P(X_n\in\cdot , \tau=n). 
$

Is then the following Theorem true ?

**Theorem**

Suppose your information mentioned above about the stochastic process $X_n$ verifies

\begin{equation}\label{eq:help2}
E[X_{\tau}] = X_0, \text{ for all }\tau\in\mathcal{T}. 
\end{equation}
Then there exists a **Martingale** $Y_n,n=0,\dots,T$ w.r.t. the same filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$ that verifies the same Limited Information Assumption above as $X_n$, i.e. a martingale $Y_n$ with

$
P(Y_n\in \cdot, \tau=n) = P(X_n\in \cdot, \tau=n), \text{ for all }n\in\{0,\dots,T\},\tau\in\mathcal{T}. 
$